# Is it possible to customize a specific double click behavior on Django admin?

Tags: python, django

Bear with my in this moment of confusion.

I have a project for a small clinic, which will be made using Python+Django.

It's a "very simple" application: they want their patients list and their consults list.

I will do this in Django, using only the admin interface(because it's the only way I know). It will be separated in two modules, one for patients, other for consults.

**Here is my question:** When the user adds a new consult on the django admin interface, is it possible for him to double click the name of that patient in the form input to open a window with the patient page? (the django admin patient module page)
[image]

Look at the screen-shot above, it's a selector with the lists of all patients(this is one of the inputs when inserting a new consult), the NORMAL BEHAVIOR of this is when you click someone, it highlights, when its highlighted and you click the arrow, it passes to the other site, or when you DOUBLE CLICK someone, it passes to the other side too.

**What I wanted to do, is when you double click someone, it opened the patient window.** Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible? Sure. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks Brandon ! I tried nothing so far, I'm studying the possibilities and needed to know that! If it wasn't, i would look on other ways to develop the solution.

Comment: You can always customize Django admin to suit your needs, whether it's through template overrides or providing your own JavaScript or CSS, etc. You just have to start digging through the Django source to find what you need.

Comment: yeah this will need to be javascript overrides.

Comment: My recommendation would be to alter the markup to add a link to view the patient detail instead of overriding the default behavior of the filter horizontal widget.

Comment: Thanks again! Could you submit as an answer? So I can mark your response